# How to make Twitter bootstrap table columns closer to each other?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a simple table from Twitter Bootstrap v3.0.3. It is just 2 columns. Below is the html code for the table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head1</th>
      <th>Head2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the columns of the table to be closer to each other. How can this be done? Thank you.

Comment: can u provide the link or jsfiddle.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the width of the table to fit the content.

The simplest way to do this would be to set `width: auto`:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto">
```